# Prevent a user from changing a specific line in a textfile

Tags: php, ftp

I'm working on a Control Panel for my communities minecraft servers. I want to keep the option to give away servers to other people too. Minecraft servers have a configfile which has the option IP/Port in it. Since people will have direct access to the file via FTP i still dont want them to change the port however the rest of it must be editable. Is there any good way to prevent users from doing so? The only idea i have at the moment is to grab the prot for each server from a database which only root users can access and then echo the port into the file just before each server start/restart.

Comment: change file permision to `777`

Comment: Why would I do that? This does not make sense at all.

Answer (score 2):

To reply on your title: "Prevent a user from changing a specific line in a textfile". This is unfortunately not possible.

Keep all editable data in one file where you grant them write-access, or create a simple GUI where the port is set, but the rest is editable (and then make sure they don't have access to change the actual settings file).

Answer (score 0):

Get the users to enter the data via a html form and build the txt file with php when the user submits the form